# Azure Redis keyspace notification issue with nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, redis, notifications, publish-subscribe

I am trying to get all notifications from Azure Redis keyspace notification using the following code, but it doesn't receive any notification, I checked the key, it got created in the Azure Redis instance. Also, I enabled Azure Redis keyspace notification by setting the `notify-keyspace-events` to `Kxg`.

Any help is appreciated:

```js
const redis = require('redis');

process.env.REDIS_CACHE_HOST_NAME = "<cachename>.redis.cache.windows.net";
process.env.REDIS_CACHE_KEY = "<cachekey>";

const client = redis.createClient(
  6380,
  process.env.REDIS_CACHE_HOST_NAME,
  {
      auth_pass: process.env.REDIS_CACHE_KEY,
      tls: { servername: process.env.REDIS_CACHE_HOST_NAME },
  });

  const client2 = redis.createClient(
    6380,
    process.env.REDIS_CACHE_HOST_NAME,
    {
        auth_pass: process.env.REDIS_CACHE_KEY,
        tls: { servername: process.env.REDIS_CACHE_HOST_NAME },
    });

const db = 0;
const notificationChannel = "__keyspace@" + db + "__:*";

client.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    console.log('100', channel , message);
});
client.subscribe(notificationChannel, function (err) {
  console.log('101' , err);

  client2.set("foo", "bar", 'EX', 10, function (err) {
    console.log('102' , err);
  });
});
```

**Update:** 
I tried C# code using the snippet here https://github.com/rustd/RedisSamples/blob/master/HelloWorld/KeySpaceNotifications.cs and it works fine which means something wrong with my NodeJs code to receive the events.

**UPDATE2:**
Using the following code I can receive my own published message, so there is no problem with subscription in general:

```
client.subscribe("pub");

client3.publish("pub", "a test message");
```

Comment: What's the SKU (Tier) of your Redis Cache?

Comment: @GauravMantri Standard C0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured it out, it works with `client.psubscribe` and `client.on("pmessage",...)`.